# XML-RPC rquests on ios

Tags: ios, xml-rpc

I need to implement XML-RPC call in my ios app. I've just came across with this lib: https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc but I have no idea how to import it into my project.

I'm a newbie in IOS so sorry if the question is "stupid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this SO question and Answer

[XMLRPC-iOS for iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362892/xmlrpc-ios-for-ios-project)

In that Answer, "mja" gave the dropBox link to download his project..
You can just download that project and learn xml-rpc from that project..

Answer (score 0):

Its a great library, I use it too. To be able to install and use it follow the below instructions.

Just install CocoaPods:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then open a Terminal window and change directory to your project's root directory and create a Podfile

```
$ touch Podfile
```

Open your created Podfile using any editor of your choice (I use TextEdit) and paste this line below:

```
pod 'xmlrpc', '~> 2.3'
```

Go back to your terminal window and run the following command (This is only done once but for the other pods just skip the pod setup command):

```
$ pod setup
```

Than run the below command:

```
$ pod install
```

Done. I also use this library is quite awesome!!!

Follow [this](http://www.monster.com.tw/archives/7140) link for example code: